# Python DataFrame not getting saved. How to permanently assign it?

Tags: python, pandas, reverse, assign, reindex

I assigned the dataframe to itself by reversing its index. But when I call it again, it's showing the old dataframe without reversing it.

```
apple = apple.reindex(index = apple.index[::-1])
apple.head()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It works?  Can you post the whole code, maybe there are problems elsewhere.

Comment: ok. I found out something weird. When I press ctrl+Enter in jupyter I get old result. ctrl+Enter again -> new result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works nice.

```
np.random.seed(45)
apple = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)), 
                     columns=list('abcd'), 
                     index=list('ABC'))

print (apple)
   a  b  c  d
A  3  0  5  3
B  4  9  8  1
C  5  9  6  8

apple = apple.reindex(index = apple.index[::-1])
print (apple)
   a  b  c  d
C  5  9  6  8
B  4  9  8  1
A  3  0  5  3
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
apple = apple.iloc[::-1]
print (apple)
   a  b  c  d
C  5  9  6  8
B  4  9  8  1
A  3  0  5  3
```

Comment: ok. I found out something weird. When I press ctrl+Enter in jupyter I get old result. ctrl+Enter again -> new result...

Comment: Unfortunately I never have this problem :(